# Using encrypted variables in Travis for Open Source

Tags: continuous-integration, open-source, travis-ci, browserstack

I have encrypted variable X in travis that I'd like Travis to use in each job (triggered on PRs), however not all PRs come from a "trusted source" (i.e. to my understanding Travis considers builds triggered by PRs coming from the repo "trusted", and those coming from users without write-access to the repo "untrusted"). Our project is Open Source, so we'd like to have Travis run our job with encrypted variable X even for "untrusted" PRs.

Travis will not release environment variables to "untrusted" jobs, so far as I can tell. How do I get around this?

Edit: It seems like this is the answer: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/jwt#List-of-Third-Party-Services-Integrated-with-the-JWT-Addon but it's only enabled for SauceLabs and I'm trying to use BrowserStack -- same question, how do I get around this? Is it implemented in BrowserStack and I just can't find the documentation?

Comment: Looks like you've been on the same journey of discovery I have – the Travis JWT solution would work, but Browserstack doesn't support it yet.

Comment: As an update -- I spoke with browserstack support, they said they have implemented this and sent a PR to Travis who is currently in the process of reviewing it. Hopefully it'll be soon!

Comment: Oh, great news  Thanks for the update.

Comment: @ocean if you want to put some more pressure on them It'd be great if you could comment on this [https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-scheduler/pull/81] (https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-scheduler/pull/81) which I've already done